# In numpy, how do I find index of element-wise maximum for several arrays, then depending on the index, query another matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following nasty code.

```
    matrix1= np.zeros((num_sim, num_states))
    matrix2= np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)
    matrix3= np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)
    matrix4= np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)

    some_matrix = ...
    some_vector = ...
    some_other_matrix = ... (same size as some_matrix)

    matrix1= some_matrix 
    matrix2[:, 1:] = some_matrix [:, :-1] + some_vector
    matrix3[:, 2:] = some_matrix [:, :-2] + some_vector * 2
    matrix4[:, 3:] = some_matrix [:, :-3] + some_vector * 3

    my_maximum = np.maximum(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4)
    result = np.zeros((num_sim, num_states))

    for k in range(my_maximum.shape()[0]):
        for kk in range(my_maximum.shape()[1]):
            if matrix1[k, kk] == my_maximum[k, kk]:
                result [k, kk] = some_other_matrix[k, kk]
            elif matrix2[k,kk] == my_maximum[k, kk]:
                result [k, kk] = some_other_matrix[k, kk-1] + some_vector[k]
            elif matrix3[k,kk] == my_maximum[k, kk]:
                result [k, kk] = some_other_matrix[k, kk-2] + some_vector[k] * 2
            else:
                result [k, kk] = some_other_matrix[k, kk-3] + some_vectorp[k] * 3
```

Is there anyway to rewrite this using mask? I see that I can define

```
matrix5 = np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)
matrix6 = np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)
matrix7 = np.full((num_sim, num_states), -np.inf)
```

This do something like

```
matrix5[:, 1] = some_other_matrix [:, :-1] + some_vector
matrix6[:, 2] = some_other_matrix [:, :-2] + some_vector * 2
matrix7[:, 3] = some_other_matrix [:, :-3] + some_vector * 3
```

Then take the pointwise max of some_other_matrix, matrix5, matrix6, matrix7, depending on the value for matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4. How do I do this?

Comment: 1) The second `elif array2[k,kk] == my_maximum[k, kk]:` appears to be dead code. 2) Should array1, array2 be matrix1, matrix2, etc, or are those different arrays?

Comment: `np.argmax` is the best tool for getting the index

Comment: Could you do something like `np.stack([matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4]).argmax(axis=0)` in order to get the index of the matrix with the highest element at that point?

Comment: @NickODell fixed in the post and will have a look at what you did. So stack the other matrices as well and apply the index?

Comment: @Lost1 Right. I'm not totally sure how to apply the `some_other_matrix[k, kk-1]` part based on the output of argmax, but I think you could use meshgrid to generate all (k, kk) indices, then subtract argmax.